# Configure AD to resolve hostnames using DNS (DC) instead of NetBIOS?

Tags: dns, active-directory, netbios

I sometimes experience that my AD  computers cannot access each other (e.g shares), using Windows Explorer, by hostname, but only by IP address.

Restarting the target computer solves the problem.

The hostnames resolve just fine on each computer, using nslookup, with DC configured as DNS server.

I expect NetBIOS to be the issue, since DNS works just fine (see above).

What can be the cause of my problem?

How can I check if NetBIOS is enabled and enable DNS for hostname lookups instead?

Comment: "Instead"? I'm sure DNS is _always_ enabled, have you verified that the computers aren't sending DNS queries?

Comment: Active Directory is DNS *BY DEFAULT.* Your DC(s) is/are DNS servers. Assuming nothing was changed lookup by hostname is one of the primary functions of AD. Often the NetBIOS name and the hostname (DNS) are the same thing, perhaps that is where the confusion is coming from?

Comment: @SteveChambers - I thought AD used NetBIOS over TCP/IP to lookup hostnames? Or is it only used for the SMB protocol? Why is it that I sometimes cannot access another computer by hostname (e.g. shares) through Windows Explorer, when the DNS works properly?